# Implementing search based on 2 fields in a java class

Tags: java, algorithm, search, collections

I am trying to present a simplified version of my requirement here for ease of understanding.

I have this class

```
public class MyClass {
   private byte[] data1;
   private byte[] data2;
   private long hash1;  // Hash value for data1
   private long hash2;  // Hash value for data2
   // getter and setters }
```

Now I need to search between 2 List instances of this class, find how many hash1's match between the 2 instances and for all matches how many corresponding hash2's match. The 2 list will have about 10 million objects of MyClass.

Now I am planning to iterate over first list and search in the second one. Is there a way I can optimize the search by sorting or ordering in any particular way? Should I sort both list or only 1?

Answer (score 0):

sort only second, iterate over first and do binary search in second, sort O(nlogn) and binary search for n item O(nlogn)

or use hashset for second, iterate over first and search in second, O(n)

Answer (score 0):

Best solution would be to iterate there is no faster solution than this. You can create Hashmap and take advantage that map does not add same key but then it has its own creation overload

Answer (score 0):

If you have to check all the elements, I think you should iterate over the first list and have a Hashmap for the second one as said AmitD.

You just have to correctly override `equals` and `hashcode` in your `MyClass` class. Finally, I will recomend you to use basic types as much as possible. For example, for the first list, instead of a list will be better to use a simple array.

Also, at the beginning you could select which of the two lists is the shorter one (if there's a difference in the size) and iterate over that one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a hashmap for one of the lists (say `list1`) -

```
Map<Long, MyClass> map = new HashMap<Long, MyClass>(list1.size());//specify the capacity
//populate map like - put(myClass.getHash1(), myClass) : for each element in the list
```

Now just iterate through the second list (there is no point in sorting both) -

```
int hash1MatchCount = 0;
int hash2MatchCount = 0;
for(MyClass myClass : list2) {
    MyClass mc = map.get(myClass.getHash1());
    if(mc != null) {
        hash1MatchCount++;
        if(myClass.getHash2() == mc.getHash2) {
            hash2MatchCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: Assuming that there is no problem regarding `hash1` being duplicates.